# Как сделать, чтобы при делении 0 на 0 писалось нельзя делить 0 на ноль

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
a = input ("Які дії будем виконувати (+ ,- ,/ ,*) : " )
b = float(input ("Введіть перше число : "))
c = float(input ("Введіть друге число : "))
if a == "+":
    d = b + c
    print ("Буде короче : " + str(d))

elif a == "*":
    g = b * c
    print ("Ти шо не знаєш шо це буде : " + str(g))

elif a == "-":
    e =  b - c
    print (e)

try:
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if a=="/" and c==0:
    print("Ти шо не знаєш шо на н0ль дiлити не можна?")
```