# Здраствуйте.Как вивести на екран што 0 на нf 0 делить нельзя в калькуляторе

Tags: python-3.x

```py
a = input ("Які дії будем виконувати (+ ,- ,/ ,*) : " )
b = float(input ("Введіть перше число : "))
c = float(input ("Введіть друге число : "))
if a == "+":
    d = b + c
    print ("Буде короче : " + str(d))

elif a == "*":
    g = b * c
    print ("Ти шо не знаєш шо це буде : " + str(g))

elif a == "-":
    e =  b - c
    print (e)

if a == "/":
    p = b / c
    print (p)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Здравствуйте.Помогите зделать так штоб при делени 0 на 0 писалося нельзя делить 0 на ноль но при введении нориальных чысел все было нормально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1041450)

Answer (score 2):

```
if a == "/":
    try:
        p = b / c
        print (p)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("На ноль делить нельзя")
```